# sql for a fuzzy search query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have an sql query for a mysql database that includes the following

```
where("UPPER(CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)) LIKE ?", params[:query])
```

Since sqlite3 doesn't have the concat function, but instead uses pipes ||, I tried to write the above as

```
where("UPPER(firstName || ' ' || lastName) LIKE ?", params[:query])
```

but the query isn't returning any results. Am I not using the `||` correctly?

note, the lowercase where is the Rails query helper.

**Update**

It turns out that the concat operator wasn't the problem, so I changed the title to this question. I'm trying to do a fuzzy search on a name,  namely to return all records that contain the search term in the person's name. For example, if you search "a", "tanja" would be a postive match the server is running this query with my sql

This is the sql that is being run (if an "a" was entered in the search box)

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, title FROM "employees" WHERE (upper(firstName ||' '||lastName) LIKE 'a')
```

The ajax request (as shown by the console) is this

```
findByName: a employee.js:20
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/employees/search/a". jquery.js:8215
[] ##empty array returned
```

If I run the query in the Rails console, it also returns empty so maybe the problem is with my sql

```
>> Employee.select("id, firstname, lastname, title").where("upper(firstName ||' '||lastName) LIKE ?", "a")
  Employee Load (0.2ms)  SELECT id, firstname, lastname, title FROM "employees" WHERE (upper(firstName ||' '||lastName) LIKE 'a')
=> []
```

However, there are records in the db with names containing the letter "a." This is the database record, for example. Can anyone explain why a query like the above (assuming the person's name contained the searched for letter) wouldn't work on a record like this.

```
[#<Employee id: 1, firstname: "Steven", lastname: "Wells", managerid: 4, title: "Software Architech", department: "Engineering", officephone: "604-999-8989", cellphone: "345-678-0987", email: "sweels@email.com", city: "Vancouer", picture: "assets/steven_wells.jpg", twitterid: "@fartbreath", blogurl: "http://blahblah.com", created_at: "2013-01-16 01:24:38", updated_at: "2013-01-16 01:24:38">,
```

Can anyone explain what the problem might be?

Comment: The LIKE operator should be case insensitive by default in sqlite3 and I just tried a query with concatenation in the WHERE clause and it worked. Could there be another problem?

Comment: @Dehalion I think it is another problem. I updated the OP with more details. Maybe my query sql is just wrong. It's supposed to be a "fuzzy search" where the records return any person whose name contains (in any position) whatever letter is searched for. For example, "a" would return "Tanja".

Comment: Try `LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')`

Comment: @ypercube it works. can you please explain for me with reference to the WHERE clause? I'd like to understand..Thanks.

Comment: @ypercube I have to translate some more queries so it'd be helpful if you could explain. I'm very inexperienced with sql, just trying to convert someone else's code. Why weren't those '%' needed in the original code?

Comment: Read about the **[`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)** and wildcards.

Comment: @ypercube I get the wildcard idea but I don't understand the structure of the statement. I don't get why the ? (which is a placeholder for the param) is between the two concats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but do you need some wildcards with the "a"? e.g. - "%a%"?

Comment: the comment by @ypercube fixed it, so yes those wildcards seem necessary, but I don't understand why they weren't needed in the original sql

Comment: The "like" operator may have different behaviors with MySQL and SQLite. I would expect that the wildcards would be needed in all cases - otherwise you are expecting a literal match.

Comment: Can you explain the structure of ypercube's comment. I understands yours %?%, but why does he put the ? in between the two concats?